# Execute Command using `Process` in Jenkins Groovy Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I am executing a `cURL` command using `sh` command with no issue.

```
pulic uploadArtifct (String user, String password, String file, String 
  location) {
  def cred = "${user}:${password}"
  def cmd = "curl -v -u cred --upload-file ${file} ${location}"

  sh cmd

  }
```

However, when I try to execute the same `cmd`, using the `Process` object. I get an error:

```
public uploadArtifct (String user, String password, String file, String 
  location) {
  def cred = "${user}:${password}"
  def cmd = "curl -v -u cred --upload-file ${file} ${location}"
  try {
   def sout = new StringBuffer(), serr = new StringBuffer()
   def proc = cmd.execute()
   proc.consumeProcessOutput(sout, serr)
   proc.waitForOrKill(1000)
   println sout
  } catch (Exception e) {
    throw new RuntimeExceptipon("Cannot execute curl, exception: [${e.getClass().getName()} - '${e.getMessage()}']")
   }
  }
```

The error that I see is:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot execute curl, exception: [java.lang.RuntimeException - 'Error running; stdout='', stderr='curl: Can't open 'Folder/artifact/file.zip'!
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
'']
```

What is it about `Process.execute()` that does not work. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue half a year ago. As i found out , the curl request that you run using the sh command is executed on the agent where the build is run

```
sh cmd  //this runs on the agent and hence finds the ${file}
```

However the second piece of code

```
def proc = cmd.execute() . //This is run on the master and hence it cannot find the ${file}
```

When you use groovy classes, it is by design to be executed on the master node. This is because the groovy engine that Jenkins uses is on the master

Comment: hm, very interesting. I only have the master node, though. But it may be executing in a different directory with different permissions. I will have to test this out. Thanks.